# Direct parameter Vs passing a class

Tags: c#

Assume that there is a class with 3 attributes.

Employee

1. Name
2. Age
3. Sal

I have a webmethod, `GetInfo`.

Does it make any difference with regard to performance for passing direct param vs. direct classs?

```
GetInfo(Employee emp) // This will internally call emp.age & return the values.

GetInfo(int age)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand your examples.  What data does GetInfo(int age) return?  Regardless, performance should be the last consideration you make for this sort of thing as it will be very nearly identical.

Comment: Get Info will return employee table info based on age, my thought is what will be the difference it makes passing direct age vs passing class.

Comment: Does it make a difference that he said *webmethod* instead of just *method*?

Comment: @Timwi - Yes its webmethod, if you are sending direct param vs. capsuling in a class, (remember if you need to send a class, does all the attributes should have some value?)

Answer (score 1):

Measure the performance for yourself to determine if one performs better than another. Create dual methods, get an instance of Stopwatch, and perform a few thousand calls to each version of the method and see if there is a demonstrable, relevant difference between the two. I doubt there is.

In the meantime, ask yourself if the `Employee` instance is even relevant to the method. If all are you doing is taking the employee's age and then passing back data that is unrelated to the specific employee, then why bother tying the method to an instance? Just take the integer parameter. For example, let's say your method call was this

```
public Employee[] GetEmployeesByAge(ArgumentType argument)
```

Does it make sense for the parameter to be an `Employee` or a simple integer? The relevant input is the age, not the `Employee` from which the age originated. If you opted to use the `Employee` as the parameter, you're limiting this method to callers that already have an instance of `Employee` standing by, which might not always be the case. (After all, they're trying to *get* the employees.)

Choose your guideline: YAGNI, KIS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The performance is probably not noticeable.

```
// Either way the performance is about the same
Employee emp = new Employee();
Info out1 = GetInfo(emp);
// or
Info out2 = GetInfo(emp.Age);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only consideration you will need to make regarding performance, is if you already have the `Employee` class or not.  If you have to create an empty `Employee` object with the age set then just use the age.

Semantically, however, it should be made obvious (by the method name) that you are retrieving by age if you take an `int` parameter as otherwise it may not be obvious what you are sending, unless you look at the method declaration, so consider changing the name to `GetInfoByAge`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the method that requires exactly what it needs, and no more.
This would improve code reuse and separation of concerns.
The performance hit shouldn't be a concern at this stage of development.